# How do I make my side menu push other elements on toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I am having trouble making the side menu push other elements out of the way (by the same width of the side menu) on toggle of the side menu. I want the side menu to push the adjacent elements out of the way as it slides in. Thank you so much, here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#hamburger").click(function() {
  $("header nav").animate({width: 'toggle'});
 });
 $("header nav").mouseleave(function() {
  $("header nav").animate({width: 'toggle'});
 });
});
```

```css
/* Universal Styles */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 text-align: center;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* Cross Styles */

aside,
.navBlock {
 font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}

/* Header Styles */

.logo {
 width: 150px; 
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .2s;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
nav,
header{
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

#hamburger {
 float: right;
 transition: all .2s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/* Navigation Styles */

 header nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #354551;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
 }
 .navBlock {
  background-color: #354551;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
     border: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     line-height: 175%;
     transition: all .2s;
 }
 header nav ul {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgrey;
 }

/* Profiles Styles */

aside ul,
aside li,
aside {
 overflow: auto;
}
aside {
 background-color: #90afc5;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 20px 9px -22px #000;
 color: #eef3f6;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #4d4d4d;
 width: 100%;
}
aside li {
 display: inline;
}
aside img {
 border-radius: 100%;
 transition: all .2s;
}

/* Footer Styles */

footer {
 font-family: 'Oswald', cursive;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size: .9em;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: #abc3d3;
 color: #2c4354;
}
footer span {
 line-height: 25px;
}

/* Showcase */

main h4 {
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 2em;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #4d4d4d;
 font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
 border: 10x dashed lightgray;
 box-shadow: 0px -20px 9px -22px #000;
}
.webShowcase img,
.logoShowcase img {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 50px auto;
 transition: all .3s;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.webShowcase h4 {
 background-color: #ffbb00;
 margin: 0;
}
.webShowcase ul,
.logoShowcase ul {
 margin-top: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
.webShowcase ul,
.webShowcase li,
.webShowcase,
.logoShowcase,
.logoShowcase li,
.logoShowcase ul {
 overflow: auto;
}
.webShowcase,
.logoShowcase {
 width: 100%;
}
.logoShowcase h4 {
 background-color: #aebd38;
 margin: 0;
}

/* Effects */

aside img:hover,
.logo:hover,
.navBlock:hover,
#hamburger:hover,
main img:hover {
 opacity: .5;
}

/* Tablet View */

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
 aside ul {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
}
/* Computer View */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 .logo {
  width: 250px;
 }
 #hamburger {
  content: url("../media/img/hamburgerResized.png");
 }
 header nav {
  width: 25%;
 }
 .webShowcase img,
 .logoShowcase img {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .webShowcase li,
 .webShowcase,
 .webShowcase ul,
 .logoShowcase,
 .logoShowcase li,
 .logoShowcase ul {
  overflow: auto;
 }
 .webShowcase li,
 .logoShowcase li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .webShowcase ul,
 .logoShowcase ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .webShowcase ul:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffcf4d;
 }
 .webShowcase ul:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
 }
 .logoShowcase ul:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #c3d062;
 }
 .logoShowcase ul:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Alexander Palermo-Wylde | Portfolio</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One|Seymour+One|Monofett|Faster+One|Rye|Eczar|Bungee+Inline|Miltonian+Tattoo|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="../../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta content="index, follow" name="robots">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="An awesome portfolio. Nuff said." name="Description">
     <meta content="portfolio, freelance, freelancer, web design, web development, alexander palermo-wylde, alexander pw" name="Keywords">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <a href="../../index.html"><img class="logo" src="../../media/img/logo.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's logo"></a>
   <img id="hamburger" src="../../media/img/hamburger.png" alt="three line navigation">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li class="navBlock navHome"><a href="../../index.html">home</a></li>
     <li class="navBlock navAbout"><a href="../pages/about/index.html">about</a></li>
     <li class="navBlock navContact"><a href="../pages/contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
     <li class="navBlock navResume"><a href="../pages/resume/index.html">resume</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <main>
    <section class="webShowcase">
     <h4>Websites</h4>
     <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="logoShowcase">
     <h4>Logos</h4>
     <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="../../media/img/web-showcase01.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
    </section>
   </main>

   <aside>
    <h4>Check me out on─</h4
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="profiles"  src="../../media/img/github.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's GitHub profile link"></a></li>
     </div>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="profiles"  src="../../media/img/codepen.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's CodePen profile link"></a></li>
     </div>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="profiles" src="../../media/img/linkedin.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's LinkedIn profile link"></a></li>
     </div>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="profiles" src="../../media/img/dribble.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's Dribble profile link"></a></li>
     </div>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="profiles" src="../../media/img/upwork.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's Upwork profile link"></a></li>
     </div>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="profiles" src="../../media/img/fiverr.png" alt="Alexander Palermo-Wylde's Elance profile link"></a></li>
     </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </aside>
  </header>
  <footer>
   <span>&copy;Alexander Palermo-Wylde</span>
  </footer>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="../../js/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `JQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#hamburger").click(function() {
 $(".fixed").toggleClass('show');
 $('main').toggleClass('fixed-active');
 $('header').toggleClass('fixed-active');
 });
});
```

This `CSS`:

```
.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 width: 300px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #354551;
 margin: 0;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 z-index: 100;
 left: -100%;
 transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
.fixed.show{
  left:0;
}
main, header {
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
main.fixed-active, header.fixed-active {
 padding-left: 300px;
 position: relative;
}
```

Look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wf0r7pc/23/)

Hope this helps!